# How to escape stacktrace in log4j (version 1.2.17)

Tags: java, exception, log4j, escaping, stack-trace

I have the following code:

```
try {
   ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error( "failed!", e );
}
```

How can I escape stacktrace?

I want escape `"` with `/"`

and `\` with `\\`

I use log4j 1.2.17 version. and properties file configuration.

**update**

current configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN,console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS z} %-5p [%t] %c{1.}#%M:%L - %m%n
log4j.logger.com.hazelcast=INFO
```

Comment: Where are you logging to that you need such a thing? Typically, that's needed for security purposes, but if you are using a plain log text file, you don't need that...or before going that way, what's your requirement?

Comment: You could create and use your own appender which handles the escaping.

Comment: @Thomas Could you show example?

Comment: Just have a look at how `ConsoleAppender` is implemented. Alternatively, if you're using an appender which supports a layout (like you're doing), provide your own `Layout` implementation and assign it to your appenders in your configuration.

Comment: I use EnhancedPatternLayout. Could I just extend it and override **format** method?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EscapedEnhancedPatternLayout extends EnhancedPatternLayout {
    @Override
    public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
        return StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(super.format(event));
    }
}
```